# Regex match (replace) all occurrences of double quotes in words between span tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of " between two span tags.

I use:

```
(?<=<span>[a-zA-Z0-9_æøåÆØÅ_,.;:!#€%&\/()$§'])*(\")(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_æøåÆØÅ_,.;:!#€%&\/()$§']*<\/span>)
```

Lookbehind for letters+specialChars

find "

Lookahead for letters+specialChars

But with the html string

```
<span>d"s"s"</span>
```

It only matches the last occurrence of the "

How can I match (eventually replace) all occurrences of double quotes within the tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: I would prefer it, as I've grabbed/matched all span tags and their contents, before looking into each of them, checking for "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother the the look behind. Instead, match `"` where `</span>` follows without finding `<span>` earlier than `</span>`, ie `"` is *inside* a span open/close pair:

```
"(?=((?!<span>).)*<\/span>)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/lqOVer1fH8sGap).

Breaking down the regex:

- `"` a literal quote
- `(?!<span>).` any character except the `<` of `<span>`
- `((?!<span>).)*` any characters up to, but not including, the `<` of `<span>`
- `(?=((?!<span>).)*<\/span>)` followed by input that encounters `</span>` before `<span>`

Comment: Ecellent, it work out fine but has a 2nd capture group as well in the case of: <span>"Mads"lkdjff</span> it selects  some of the "normal" letters as well - but it's enough to work with :-)

Comment: @Pedellen the regex only consumes a single quote character. Everything else in the regex is a look ahead (which contains a negative look ahead), and look arounds do not consume or capture. No groups are captured by this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
/(?<=<span>[^<>]*)"(?=[^<>]*<\/span>)/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Vd6gXj/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <span>                   '<span>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<>]*                   any character except: '<', '>' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<>]*                   any character except: '<', '>' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    span>                    'span>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work? Does not capture any of the " characters?